# How to profile expensive useSelector functions in React Redux, in relation to the render time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I had a component that was rendered with an overzealous selector, like so: (example is simplified)

```js
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
const aLotOfData = useSelector(state => {
    return { ...state.object };
});
```

This was re-rendering each time any value in the `state` changed. So I have changed it to be:

```js
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import equalsES6 from 'fast-deep-equal/es6';
const aLotOfData = useSelector(state => {
    return processKeys(state.object); // returns a new object each time
}, equalsES6);
```

`processKeys` selects a specific subset of keys that we need and transforms their values, so that the component only re-renders when the given values change. I need `equalsES6` because the returned object is nested. I could also split out the hook into multiple individual selectors.

I have checked with React Devtools, and this prevents unnecessary renders. Now, I am concerned that my deep equals might be slightly expensive. Or my `processKeys` function might be slightly expensive.

**Question:** how can I profile the cost of my `useSelector` hooks in my component? My aim is to prove that one/multiple expensive hook functions might still be cheaper than an unnecessary re-render. I know my component takes 100ms to render, from the React DevTools. So I want to get the timing information for the expensive hooks, so I can compare between the two.